# Error 502 when attempting Gitlab Jenkins webhook

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

I'm trying to set up a webhook between both my Gitlab server and Jenkins server, however when using the "test" dropdown box in Gitlab's webhook page, I receive the following error:

```html
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 502 <html> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center> </body> </html>
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this problem? Or at least some ways to troubleshoot the issue? I don't get any output when I set up a system logger on Jenkins for `com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins`... Thanks in advance.